# How to modify save function for model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem. In my Department model I override save function. The logic is next: every Department can have one superior department, and one department can have many subsidiary dep's. My first `if` works correctly, if I choose superior dep's, when save existing instance, this superior in result have self as subsidiary.

But my second `if` doesn't work. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
class Department(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300,              blank=True, verbose_name='description')
    subsidiary  = models.ManyToManyField(   'self', blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='subsidiary_name')
    superior    = models.ForeignKey(        'self', null=True,  blank=True, related_name='superior_name', on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    manager     = models.ForeignKey(        Manager, related_name='manager_name', null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    status      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    proxy       = models.ForeignKey(        Manager, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, blank=True, verbose_name='Proxy', null=True, related_name='proxy_name')       # TODO
    history     = HistoricalRecords()

    def get_subsidiary(self):
        return "\n".join([p.title for p in self.subsidiary.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # override superior instance by adding subsidiary instance automatically
        if self.superior:
            superior_department = Department.objects.get(title=self.superior.title)
            superior_department.subsidiary.add(self)

        if self.subsidiary:
            subsidiary_dep = Department.objects.filter(title__in=self.subsidiary.values('title'))
            for dep in subsidiary_dep:
                dep.superior.add(self)
```

Comment: if the subsidiary already has a superior set do you want to override? Also, instead of `if self.subsidary` just do the loop. Also not sure why you are using titles. Use self or id as they are likely to be indexed, and title is not necessarily unique. It also looks like you are using `.add` on the superior ForeignKey - I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: you're right, I've just deleted subsidiary, and stay only superior :)